# php mvc form not working

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

i want to update the fields below but my form is not working. it is not storing data what should i do. i used jquery accordion fo r the fields so it will click the item he wants to edit then update the fields then submit. but it is not working.

VIEW

```
    foreach($people as $row){
                echo "<h3>".$row->service."</h3>";  
                echo "<form action='".base_url()."some_controller/updateCI' method='post'> <div>Service ID: <input type=text name=id value='".$row->id."' size=27px/><br>Service Name: <input type=text name=name value='".$row->service."'><input type='button' class='classname' value='Save'/></form></div>";
        }
```

?>

CONTROLLER

```
public function updateCI(){
    $this->load->model('some_model');

    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $servName = $this->input->post('name');


    $success = $this->some_model->updateCI($id,$servName);

    if($success == TRUE)
        $this->editCI_page(TRUE);
    else $this->editCI_page(FALSE);
}
```

MODEL

```
public function updateCI($id,$servName){
    //$name = $this->db->escape_str($name);
    $appID = $this->db->escape_str($id);
    $ciName = $this->db->escape_str($servName);


    $queryStr = "UPDATE appwarehouse.service SET id='$appID',service='$ciName' WHERE id = '$appID';";
    $query = $this->db->query($queryStr);
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: so for each field you are creating one form ?

Comment: yes yes how will it work

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this in your model:

```
       $data = array(
           'title' => $title,
           'name' => $name,
           'date' => $date
        );

     $this->db->where('id', $id);
     $this->db->update('mytable', $data);
```

I would recommend you to use the active record which are available for codeigniter. For more information visit the below link:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html